# ASP.NET : when querying SQL Server for one field, autofill another field with value from database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, frontend

This is the markup I have

```
<td>
    <asp:ComboBox ID="cbArtikal" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
           AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" DataSourceID="ssArtikal" 
           DataTextField="Artikal" DataValueField="Artikal" MaxLength="0" 
           style="display: inline;">
     </asp:ComboBox>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ssArtikal" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Artikal] FROM [Stavke_Dokumenta]">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
<td>
       <asp:ComboBox ID="cbJM" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
              AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" DataSourceID="ssJM" DataTextField="JM" 
              DataValueField="JM" MaxLength="0" style="display: inline;">
        </asp:ComboBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ssJM" runat="server" 
              ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
              SelectCommand="SELECT [JM] FROM [Stavke_Dokumenta]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
```

What I would like is to do is autofill the second field when first one is selected, but to still have the option to change the value with dropbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `OnChange` event on the first combobox, with something like:

```
cbJM.SelectedItem = cbArtikal.Items.SelectedItem;
```

Or take this approach:

```
cbJM.SelectedItem = cbArtikal.Items.FindByValue("The Selected Value")
```